# Working days on SQL Server using CTE in a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a function to return the number of working days between 2 dates. I have a table with all the bank holidays in which has two fields: BHID and BHDate.

I've written the following SELECT query to test out my theory and it works nicely:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Date, @EndDate AS Date

SET @StartDate = '2015-01-01'
SET @EndDate = '2015-07-01'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate, @StartDate AS DateCalc
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate, DATEADD(dd, 1, DateCalc) AS DateCalc FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, DateCalc) <= EndDate)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Days
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN psd.dbo.LUBankHolidays BH
ON CTE.DateCalc = BH.BHDate
WHERE BHID IS NULL
AND LEFT(DATENAME(dw, DateCalc) ,1) <> 'S'
option (Maxrecursion 0);
```

But when I try and put it in a function I get some errors around the SET line, it could be me just not being quite as good on functions as the rest of my knowledge or I was wondering whether it was to do with the CTE not having been used ahead of the SET line? Here's my attempt:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkingDays]
(@StartDate AS Date, @EndDate AS Date
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Days AS INT

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate, @StartDate AS DateCalc
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate, DATEADD(dd, 1, DateCalc) AS DateCalc FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, DateCalc) <= EndDate)

SET @Days = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Days
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN psd.dbo.LUBankHolidays BH
ON CTE.DateCalc = BH.BHDate
WHERE BHID IS NULL
AND LEFT(DATENAME(dw, DateCalc) ,1) <> 'S'
option (Maxrecursion 0);)

RETURN @Days

END
```

I even tried inserting the result of the INT into a temporary table and then dropping this after setting @Days before then returning @Days but this then results in an error regarding not being allowed to produce temporary tables as part of a function.

Any help would be great, I'm sure it's a small thing but just escaping me currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a CTE can only be used in a query, rather than using `SET` to set the variable, use `SELECT` instead:

```
SELECT @Days = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Days
FROM CTE …
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx):

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns.

Comment: Thanks, so I'll just change the SET part for SELECT and that'll probably fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out with [stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd)'s help:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkingDays]
(@StartDate AS Date, @EndDate AS Date
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Days AS INT

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate, @StartDate AS DateCalc
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate, DATEADD(dd, 1, DateCalc) AS DateCalc FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, DateCalc) <= EndDate)

SELECT @Days = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Days
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN psd.dbo.LUBankHolidays BH
ON CTE.DateCalc = BH.BHDate
WHERE BHID IS NULL
AND LEFT(DATENAME(dw, DateCalc) ,1) <> 'S')
option (Maxrecursion 0);

RETURN @Days

END
```

Thanks All

Answer (score -1):

Use this function

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkingDays]
    (@Start_Date AS Date, @end_Date AS Date
    )
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Days AS INT

        WITH    AllDays
                  AS ( SELECT   @start_date AS [Date], 1 AS [level]
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]), [level] + 1
                       FROM     AllDays
                       WHERE    [Date] < @end_date )

   SELECT @Days =COUNT(*) AS Days
    FROM AllDays
    LEFT JOIN psd.dbo.LUBankHolidays BH
    ON AllDays.Date= BH.BHDate
    WHERE BHID IS NULL
    AND LEFT(DATENAME(dw, AllDays.Date) ,1) <> 'S'

    RETURN @Days

    END
```

Comment: Thanks, with this version I'm getting the "missing semicolon" error before the WITH statement for AllDays, if I put this in I then get the same incorrect syntax error as I'm experiencing with my code at SET.

Comment: I meant thanks for attempting to help, your code didn't work and suffered from the same error as my original code in that it had SET and not SELECT. I think to vote it would be misleading in that it it didn't further my search for the correct answer.